# functioning of replace()

Tags: python, function, replace

```
print("abc".replace("","|")) #Explain this 
#|a|b|c|

print("".replace("","abc"))
#abc

print("".replace("","abc",3))
#no output why? is this bug ?
```

I am really unable to understand this lines please explain it breefly...

Comment: Why you passed 3? what are you expecting in print("".replace("","abc",3))

Comment: I just need explanation bro... unable to understand first and last line

Comment: Maybe worth reading the source code for [stringobject.c](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c) to understand this behavior. Search for "there is no way beyond this". The documentation for [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) is anything but clear on what the behavior will be (quite typical of Python imo).

Comment: @RatnapalShende so, it looks like you are correct in your inference that this is a bug (or at least undefined behavior) and it has been addressed in Python 3.9 per https://bugs.python.org/issue28029. I think you should accept Saeed's answer.

Comment: Please do not put commentary in your question. We need questions to be useful for the long haul, the text you added is of no use to someone visiting in a few years time with a similar problem, trying to see if the answers will help them too. Use comments for that, but take into account that [feedback on votes is not mandatory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin). I have removed the comments and locked the post for a while to make sure you understand not to add those back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line you're trying to replace each `nothing` character with `|`, so the output should be and is `a|b|c` . If your code was like `a b c`, then your output would be `|a| |b| |c|`

Regarding the last line and your expected output which should be `abcabcabc`, the `replace` function **replaces**, not **multiplies**. So you can modify your code to thing like this, that first of all you replace your desired characters and then multiply them by 3 to reach what you want.

```
print("".replace("", "abc")*3)
```

Output is now `abcabcabc`.

But about your code, your telling Python interpreter that `hey, find three '' and replace them by 'abc'`, but your code includes only one `nothing` and you cannot replace 3 of nothing by `abc` and get empty value.

That is not a bug in fact.

**Edit**

I searched a bit more and figured out [Issue 28029](https://bugs.python.org/issue28029) was a bug like your case in Python Bugs in Python version 3.8. I checked it again with Python 3.9 IDLE and now it is working fine:

```
print(''.replace('', 'abc', 3))
abc
```

Comment: The count parameter is the maximum number of occurrences to replace, not the minimum.

Comment: Yes you're right, but when you have an empty string, then it only works with no `count` argument in fact..

Comment: And the question is why that happens. When you say "no max occurrences (-1)" then it replaces one occurrence. When you say "max one occurrence (1)" it replaces zero occurrences.

Comment: I tried again with Python 3.9 and the new version of Python is behaving correct. Now it returns `abc` even if you set the count to to 3, because it has only one so it returns `abc`. It seems it was a bug with Issue number 28029 in Python Bugs and it is fixed in version 3.9. I'm very happy you are challenging me so I research to find the answer (I know you know the answer).

Comment: My Pleaser jarmod :)

Answer (score 0):

According to doc (`help(str.replace)`):

```
replace(self, old, new, count=-1, /)
Return a copy with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.
    count
     Maximum number of occurrences to replace.
     -1 (the default value) means replace all occurrences.
    
    If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are
    replaced.
```

Basically you're setting the limit of occurences to be replaced.

For what concern the first example:

it seems that `print("abc".replace("","|"))` fall in a special case handle by python developers like that. Checking the code here [zero length special-case](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/865c3b257fe38154a4320c7ee6afb416f665b9c2/Objects/stringlib/transmogrify.h#L694).

You switch from *python* to *c*, there you can read that when the string to be replaced has 0 length the function `stringlib_replace_interleave` is called.
The example said it will:

```
/* insert the 'to' bytes everywhere.    */
/*    >>> b"Python".replace(b"", b".")  */
/*    b'.P.y.t.h.o.n.'                  */
```

For all the other cases you can check [string replace implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/865c3b257fe38154a4320c7ee6afb416f665b9c2/Objects/stringlib/transmogrify.h).

Comment: explain first line bro ```print("abc".replace("", "|"))```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think this answer explains the symptoms? The default of -1 means replace all occurrences, which does result in the empty string being replaced (once). So why doesn't 1 (or 2 or 3) also result in the empty string being replaced once? The number of occurrences in the -1 case seems to be one so why does passing count=1 not result in the same output?